# C# api response comes back with backslashes before all json properties

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, webclient

When I get my response back from this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Organisation> GetAll()
    {
        string requestUrl = BlaBla.APIURL + "/org/";
        //string response = await postRequest.AuthenticatedGetData(requestUrl, BlablaDataContext.Contract.AccessToken).Result;
        AuthenticatedGetData(requestUrl, BlaBla.Contract.AccessToken);

        IEnumerable<Organisation> organisations = new Organisation[] {};
        return organisations;
    }

    public override void WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string response = e.Result;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Contract));
            Contract contract = (Contract)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }
```

`...
string response = e.Result();`

is returning the following:

```
response"[{\"status\":\"active\",\"segment\":null,\"contract_status\":\"none\",\"name\":\"Projects with James\",\"rights\...
```

How do I stop this from happening as I cannot use http://json2csharp.com/ to convert my json to csharp objects...

My webclient looks like this:

```
abstract public class PostRequest
{
    public void AuthenticatedGetData(string url, string accessToken)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(this.WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url + "?oauth_token=" + accessToken));
    }

    public abstract void WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e);
}
```

Comment: A quick workaround would be to use .Replace("\","") but I am not sure if this is an acceptable solution in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the string actually has backslashes in it, and it's not Visual Studio's visualizer doing it?  If you punch that result out to a file, what's it look like?

The giveaway is that the string starts with a `"` ...

Comment: How do I write the content to a file. bit new to c#.

Comment: @JamesT [`File.WriteAllText(fileName, resultString)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - windows phone 8 :(

Comment: I wrote to console instead

Comment: Just click on the magnifying glass next to the watch object to get the preview window. I bet the slashes disappear.

Answer (score 0):

My Friend the backslash are appearing because your converting it to string! use : http://james.newtonking.com/json it is the best (in my opinion) Json lib for WP. its very easy to use and has ALOT of power.